# Trying to update a value with Angular using a function in HTML isn't updating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="currentTimeStartHour" style="width: 33%" ng-change="UpdateTime(this)">
   <option ng-repeat="hour in choices" value="{{hour.id}}">{{hour.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Somewhere else (in the HTML Page)...

```
{{totalHours}}
```

What I want to do is everytime this select field is updated, I want to run a function that updates and recalculates another value which is displayed earlier in the code. This is that very function:

```
$scope.UpdateTime = function() {
  totalHours = currentTimeStartHour - 3;
  return totalHours;
};
```

The result I currently get is that the function doesn't run at all. I am new to angular and have been struggling with this for a while now. Can someone please help me out or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have to use **$scope** on your variables inside the controller function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="currentTimeStartHour"
        ng-change="UpdateTime()">
   <option ng-repeat="hour in choices" value="{{hour.id}}">{{hour.name}}</option>
</select>

{{totalHours}}
```

in Controller

```
$scope.UpdateTime = function() {

  $scope.totalHours = $scope.currentTimeStartHour - 3;

};
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. I'm very new to angular so I was confused. I know I could read tutorials but I've kinda been thrown in the deep end of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.UpdateTime = function(currentTimeStartHour) {
  $scope.totalHours = currentTimeStartHour - 3;
};
```

In your HTML :

```
<select ng-model="currentTimeStartHour" style="width: 33%" ng-change="UpdateTime(currentTimeStartHour)">
   <option ng-repeat="hour in choices" value="{{hour.id}}">{{hour.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!